# Proving $x + \sin x + \sin(x + \sin x) + \sin(x + \sin x + \sin(x + \sin x)) + ... = \pi $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, recurrence-relations, recursion

I was given a very interesting sum of series by a friend. The problem is to prove that if $ x \in (0, 2\pi) $ , then

$$ x + \sin x + \sin(x + \sin x) + \sin(x + \sin x + \sin(x + \sin x)) + ... = \pi $$

The $n^{th}$ term is related to the sum of all the previous $n-1$ terms as

$$ T_n = \sin ( S_{n-1} ) $$

I tried doing something using this relation, which didn't yield anything significant.
I also tried using Euler's form of a complex number to somehow convert it into a more manageable series, which also failed miserably.
Any hints or approaches would be appreciated.
The problem is supposed to be at the high school level.

Comment: Well, this is far from rigorous but assume this converges to something, say $L.$ Then, this $L$ must satisfy $L+\sin(L)=L.$ This implies $L=\pi.$

Comment: where did you get this question from ?

Comment: I was told it came in a high school examination in India.

Comment: It appears that $\{S_n\}$ is an increasing sequence for $0<x<\pi$, which then implies that it must be bounded above (by $\pi$). This implies that it must converge to something, and then @aqualubix's comment finishes it off. Similarly, $\{S_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below by $\pi$ for $\pi<x<2\pi$.

Comment: How can we prove its convergence?

Comment: @ShivanshJaiswal probably by [convergence of fixed point iteration theorem](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-convergence-of-the-fixed-point-method)

Comment: What are your efforts?

Comment: @ShivanshJaiswal: But it is the same, only with $a_0 = x$ instead of $a_0 = 3$. Write down the first few terms and you should see it: $a_0 =x$, $a_1 = a_0 + \sin a_0 = x + \sin x$, $a_2 = a_1 + \sin a_1 = x + \sin x + \sin(x + \sin x)$, ...